# How to see how many people are accessing a ssas cube?

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube, msbi, cubes

I wanted to know how many people are accessing a particular ssas cube. Please let me know the process to find them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simple way to get connected users from a cube. You can use a couple of different tools to collect that information (along with lot's of other information as well).

To get a list for users currently connected to a SSAS instance, you might use [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15). Then you can filter one cube from the resulting data.

For tracking users extended period of time, you can use [Extended events](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6121/monitoring-sql-server-analysis-services-with-extended-events/)

Both of these tools create data for a lot of data and you'll need to parse distinct users from that is some way.

Answer (score 0):

To see the current sessions:

```
SELECT * FROM $System.DISCOVER_SESSIONS
```